# Creating a Combined 301 Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

We are being advised by our SEO agency to reduce the number of "chained" redirects we have.

So, for example:
URL A - http://www.sitename.co.uk/SHOPPING-CATEGORIES/product_name

redirects to its https version
(this is redirect 1, changing http to https)

the redirected url then redirects to the same url but all in lower case. So /SHOPPING-CATEGORIES/ becomes /shopping-categories/ (this is redirect 2, changing all urls to lower case as they are case sensitive)

the redirected url then redirects to 
URL B - https://www.sitename.co.uk/category/product_name
(this is redirect 3 which removes the string /shopping-categories because this is no longer used in any url)

The above creates three separate redirects where what is actually wanted/needed is

URL A
redirects to 
URL B

How can this be best achieved?

ADDITION: For clarity, this site is on a dedicated server and so it is not set up as a virtual host. Would all this be easier if were using NGINX?

Thanks very much for any input

Comment: To be absolutely clear, here: an Apache VirtualHost is nothing similar to a virtual machine. All a VirtualHost block does is tell Apache "the site in this directory will handle these types of requests with this configuration". In all likelihood your dedicated server already has a configuration for your site in a `<VirtualHost>` block. If it does not, all it takes to add one is two to four additional lines in a configuration file - that's all there is to it. That in mind, entirely switching webservers would be the more difficult and time-consuming solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `VirtualHost` config for the site, I think `mod_rewrite` would to be up to the task (when placed in said `<VirtualHost>` directive block):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteMap lc int:tolower 

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:$0} [R=301]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/shopping-categories/(.*)$ $1/category/$2 [R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

You may need to restart the Apache service to re-parse the `VirtualHost` configuration.

The `RewriteMap` directive maps a "to lowercase" behavior that's packaged with `mod_rewrite`, and is the only directive which absolutely must be in the `<VirtualHost>` directive block. All other directives could be placed in a `.htaccess` file or `<Directory>` directive block.

- `RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:$0} [R=301]`: If the requested URI-path contains an uppercase letter, apply the "to lowercase" map against the entire path and set up a permanent redirect.
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)/shopping-categories/(.*)$ $1/category/$2 [R=301]`: If the (now most definitely lowercase) URI-path contains "/shopping-categories/", replace it with "/category/" and set up a permanent redirect.
- `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`: If the request was not made using HTTPS...

  - `RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301]`: ...rewrite it using the HTTPS schema and set up a permanent redirect.

As no `L` or `END` flags are specified, Apache will test all rewrite rules and redirect only once if any rule was applied.

---

### ADDENDUM

The above directives should function equally as well in a server-level configuration (often `httpd.conf`). However, a `VirtualHost` block is preferable as it limits the changes to specifically to applicable requests (and thus resource overhead, behavior alterations, etc.). If your dedicated server does not appear to load a `<VirtualHost>` directive block for your website at any point you can easily implement one, even if you only plan on hosting one website on the server - this is a fairly standard practice and will not introduce any great complexity nor resource overhead to the webserver. Review the Apache documentation on [Configuration Files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html) and the [VirtualHost examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/examples.html#default) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your input - I much appreciate the effort, but this site is on a dedicated server and so it is not set up as a virtual host. Any other ideas? Would this be easier if were using NGINX?

Comment: @jdeb901 I think you're misunderstanding what an Apache `<VirtualHost>` block is. I've clarified in a comment on your question. However, my posted solution should work in the top-level server configuration as well. It's possible that it is easier to achieve your desired outcome with Nginx, but the time and effort required to switch web-servers far exceeds that required to make the change in Apache.